# VBA Disable Outlook Addin?

Tags: vba, outlook

What VBA code would I use to disable an Outlook Add-In? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Needs more details. Why do you want to do this with VBA? What add-in?

Comment: I need VBA code to disable, as an example, Bananatag or other Add-Ins that cause problems. I am not sure how to better explain my question. The code would be part of a larger script.

Answer (score 0):

Find the addin you are after in the `Application.COMAddins` collection (e.g. by the `COMAddin.Description`, `ProgId`, or `Guid` property), then set the `COMAddin.Connect` property to false.

Keep in mind that that you can only disable/enable addins installed in HKCU. The ones installed in HKLM can only be modified by the admin.